# How to install Firefox browser without app store

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, firefox

Im new to Iphone. For a good reason, I do not wish to log into anything cloud related, hence no app store access. I'd like to install firefox browser. On my android phone, I just downloaded an APK from apkpure.com. I assume it's the same here. However, I'd very much prefer to get IPA from somewhere trusted. It doesn't seem like Firefox is posting their binaries anywhere else except for apple store and android store. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apps for iPhone come from the App Store. That's it. Nowhere else. What's wrong with getting it from there?

Comment: Either log into the Apple Store or jailbreak so you can side load.  There's no 3rd party source for apps you're interested in.

Comment: @Tetsujin: simple: I want to keep most of my private data away from cloud. Once you log in - you will automatically get some of that data out to the cloud.

Comment: Then you'll have to jailbreak, or not use the phone. You had to set up an Apple ID to register it to you in the first place, otherwise you're not its owner & you have no real control over it. Far rather sign up to a single company who monitor the content of all apps before they're allowed on the store than trust to some random un-policed app from some zero-trust site on the open internet.